# How do I fix Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() error

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

When I try to log in it gives me this error.

> Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Here is the code for the file:

```
<?php

  //get values form login.php
  $username = $_POST['user'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];

  //prevent MSQL injections
  $username = stripcslashes($username);
  $password = stripcslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


  //connect to server and select database
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("loginregister");

  //query the database for the user
  $result = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die("faield to query database ".mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
    echo "You logged in successfully! Welcome ".$row['username'];
  } else {
    echo "Login Failed";
  }
?>
```

The expected result is after I log in it says you logged in successfully. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use MySQLi or PDO with a prepared statement instead, that will fix your issue.

Comment: Also, UNHASHED passwords are ***not secure at all***!

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: and How do I hash the password?

Comment: https://php.net/mysqli-prepare or https://php.net/pdo-prepare - you cannot use `mysql_` - its outdated and not supported in newer versions of PHP.

Comment: See https://php.net/password_hash for hashing passwords

Comment: Also `$row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password` is prone the [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) the safe method is [hash_equals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php)

Comment: ... but for password_hash() which @Qirel is suggesting you should use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to prevent timing attacks.

Comment: Basically `select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'` can be totally prone to timing attacks also especially when the username and password are both in the btree index.. ive once did research/tests on a local MySQL server it seamt totally possible to do a timing attack when selecting data as databases are designed to return data as soon as possible... Ideally you should  **only** use the `WHERE` on username and compare the password with a safe hash compare..